# Three.js, 256×256 png textures crash chrome tab

Tags: memory, three.js, load, textures

Loading 256x256 textures into Three.js materials, which are then used for planegeometry deformation. Encountering a bottleneck at 15th texture. Chrome apparently crashes at the render call. When each mesh is added to scene, I call the renderer.render call, but the sequence is pretty tight, so I believe, the gpu bus may be overwhelmed. It is hard to believe that a small number of such small textures is enough to cause this. Cpu memory is not a problem, as textures are loaded into cpu and if meshes are not added to scene, there is no crash. Also, there is a significant delay while the textures are being copied from cpu to gpu.

```js
function loadTexture(texture) {
    var x = 512;
    var y = 512;
    var dx = 256;
    var dy = 256;

    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(x, y, dx, dy);

    var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
        uniforms: {
            heightMap: {
                type: "t",
                value: texture
            }
        },
        vertexShader: vertexShader,
        fragmentShader: fragmentShader
    });

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    scene.add(mesh);

    this.renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Comment: ypv welcome to SO. It really helps the community to be able to see the code you want our help debugging otherwise we are left to kinda guess and you will not get very good responses.

Comment: I just noticed that I am duplicating PlaneGeometry for all the textures. Let me try to re-use geometry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PlaneGeometries are turning out to be expensive in Three.js r76. I cannot create more than 14 of these (at mentioned resolution of 256x256 data points). I happen to need many but a limited amount of plane geometries, so I can continue to push against this limit but eventually I will need more memory for the PlaneGeometries. This bottleneck is GPU only, as this happens only on renderer.render call.